# Integer comparision using DBD::SQLite

Tags: perl, sqlite, comparison, integer, dbi

I'm facing a problem with DBIx::Class against an SQLite3 database.

If you don't want to read the following in full, here's the TL;DR version:

> Is there a way to force DBD::SQLite to treat integer fields as being unsigned, when it comes to comparisons?

The table definition is here:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(entry);
0|entry_key|INTEGER|1||1
1|node|varchar(256)|1||0
2|object_type|varchar(128)|1||0
3|object_id|int|1||0
4|copy_id|tinyint|0||0
5|seq_number|int|1||0
6|root_seq_number|int|1||0
7|first_error|int|1||0
8|last_error|int|1||0
9|error_count|int|1||0
10|error_id|int|1||0
11|error_code|int|0||0
12|status|varchar(64)|1||0
13|type|varchar(64)|1||0
14|sense|char(256)|0||0
```

The fields of interest are `first_error` and `last_error`. These fields contain epoch time values. **Thus, they are 32-bit numbers, but they are less than 2147483647**

In my code, I have the following:

```
my @entries =  $self->{row}->search_related_rs('eventlog_entries')
                           ->search_related('entry', {
                             first_error => {'>', $range->{start}},
                             last_error  => {'<', $range->{end}},
                           }
           )->all();
```

`start` is set to 0; `end` is set to `2**32 - 1`

When run with `DBI_TRACE=1`, I get:

```
<- prepare_cached('SELECT entry.entry_key, entry.node, entry.object_type,
                   entry.object_id, entry.copy_id, entry.seq_number,
                   entry.root_seq_number, entry.first_error, entry.last_error,
                   entry.error_count, entry.error_id, entry.error_code, entry.status,
                   entry.type, entry.sense FROM eventlog_entry me  JOIN entry entry ON
                   entry.entry_key = me.entry_key WHERE ( ( ( first_error > ? AND
                     last_error < ? ) AND me.eventlog_key = ? ) )', 
                  HASH(0x2472b54), ...)= ( DBI::st=HASH(0x2442efc) ) [1 items] 
   at DBI.pm line 2245
<- bind_param(1, 0, ...)= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 1574
<- bind_param(2, '4294967295', ...)= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 1574
<- bind_param(3, 1, ...)= ( 1 ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 1574
<- execute= ( '0E0' ) [1 items] at DBI.pm line 1586
<- fetchall_arrayref= ( [ ] ) [1 items] row-1 at Cursor.pm line 133
```

In this case, `@entries` is an empty array.

On the other hand, if I set `end` is set to `2**31 - 1`, everything works.

My hyopthesis is this:

SQLite fields have an 'affinity', which means that the fields are recognised as integers, but they have no native size. Thus, SQLite "guesses" what the size is, based on the contents of the field. Since the value in the `last_error` field is less than 2147483647, but greater than 16777215, I'm guessing that SQLite is treating the field as a SIGNED INTEGER (i.e. signed 32-bit number).

As such, my guess is that, when the `bind_param` takes place, some kind of inspection is done, which results in DBI identifying `last_error` as a SIGNED INTEGER. As a result, the value of 4294967295 overflows, or gets squished to zero, or something like that, and the comparison works incorrectly.

Thus, my question(s):

1. Is this hypothesis correct (according to some documentation that I've overlooked)? or
2. Is there a way to confirm this hypothesis?
3. Is this a bug, or is there a sensible workaround, bearing in mind that I'm using DBIx::Class, so I'm somewhat abstracted away from the database.

Comment: You are right about the type 'affinity'. See section 2.0 "Type Affinity" in the sqlite data types documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)  sqlite always treats integers as unsigned, so I think the problem is with `DBD::SQLite`

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, I see: "INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value."... so INTEGERs are signed... so the problem is actually the inferred size.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say "sql always treats integers as _signed_" not "unsigned" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using literal sql in your query:

```
my $cond = " < $range->{end} ";

my @entries =  $self->{row}->search_related_rs('eventlog_entries')
                       ->search_related('entry', {
                         first_error => {'>', $range->{start}},
                         last_error  => \$cond,
                       }
       )->all();
```

Should work if perl stringifies `$range->[end}` as a positive number.

Comment: I've give you an upvote, because that is an effective solution. However, I'd still like to understand properly what is happening here and if there's a way to address the root problem.